# Is linq's let keyword better than its into keyword?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently brushing up on LINQ and am trying to comprehend the difference between the `let` and using the `into` keyword. So far the `let` keyword seems better than the `into` keyword as far as my understanding goes.

The `into` keyword essentially allows one to continue a query after a projection. (Just want to state explicitly that I'm not referring to the one for group join.)

Given an array of names it allows one to do the following:

```
var intoQuery =
  from n in names
  select Regex.Replace(n, "[aeiou]", "")
  into noVowel
  where noVowel.Length > 2
  select noVowel;
```

It takes the result of the select and places it into the `noVowel` variable which then allows one to introduce additional `where`, `orderby`, and `select` clauses. Once the `noVowel` variable is created, the `n` variable is no longer available.

The `let` keyword, on the other hand, uses temp anonymous types to allow you to reuse more than one variable at a time.

You can do the following:

```
var letQuery =
  from n in names
  let noVowel = Regex.Replace(n, "[aeiou]", "")
  where noVowel.Length > 2
  select noVowel;
```

Both the `noVowel` and `n` variables are available for use (even though I haven't used it in this case).

While I can see the difference, I can't quite understand why one would want to use the `into` keyword over the `let` keyword unless one explicitly wanted to make sure that previous variables were not able to be used in latter parts of the query.

So, is there a good reason why both keywords exist?

Comment: Is it a typo in `let` example - `where noVowel`, what is `noVowel` in that case?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, because they're doing different things, as you've said.

`select ... into` effectively isolates the whole of one query and lets you use it as the input to a new query. Personally I *usually* prefer to do this via two variables:

```
var tmp = from n in names
          select Regex.Replace(n, "[aeiou]", "");

var noVowels = from noVowel in tmp
               where noVowel.Length > 2
               select noVowel;
```

(Admittedly in this case I would do it with dot notation in two lines, but ignoring that...)

Often you don't *want* the whole baggage of the earlier part of the query - which is when you use `select ... into` or split the query in two as per the above example. Not only does that mean the earlier parts of the query can't be used when they shouldn't be, it simplifies what's going on - and of course it means there's potentially less copying going on at each step.

On the other hand, when you *do* want to keep the rest of the context, `let` makes more sense.

Comment: Does the usage of one or the other affect the generated SQL?

Answer (score 44):

The primary difference is the `let` injects the variable into the context/scope, where `into` creates a new context/scope.

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to know the difference on DB side, wrote 2 Entity Framework queries.

- Let

  ```
  from u in Users
  let noVowel = u.FirstName.Replace("a","").Replace("e","").Replace("i","")
  where noVowel.Length >5
  select new {u.FirstName, noVowel}
  ```
- Into

  ```
  from u in Users
  select u.FirstName.Replace("a","").Replace("e","").Replace("i","")
  into noVowel
  where noVowel.Length >5
  select noVowel
  ```

The generated SQLs are almost **identical**. The SQL is not perfect,  same string process code are repeated on 2 places (where and select).

```
SELECT 1 AS [C1], [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Extent1].[FirstName], N'a', N''), N'e', N''), N'i', N'') AS [C2]
FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( CAST(LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Extent1].[FirstName], N'a', N''), N'e', N''), N'i', N'')) AS int)) > 5
GO

SELECT 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Extent1].[FirstName], N'a', N''), N'e', N''), N'i', N'') AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( CAST(LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Extent1].[FirstName], N'a', N''), N'e', N''), N'i', N'')) AS int)) > 5
```

Here is the SQL generated by LINQ-to-SQL

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'a'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p2 NVarChar(1000) = 'e'
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p4 NVarChar(1000) = 'i'
DECLARE @p5 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p6 Int = 5
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t1].[FirstName], [t1].[value] AS [noVowel]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[FirstName], REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([t0].[FirstName], @p0, @p1), @p2, @p3), @p4, @p5) AS [value]
    FROM [User] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE LEN([t1].[value]) > @p6
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'a'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p2 NVarChar(1000) = 'e'
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p4 NVarChar(1000) = 'i'
DECLARE @p5 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p6 Int = 5
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t1].[value]
FROM (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([t0].[FirstName], @p0, @p1), @p2, @p3), @p4, @p5) AS [value]
    FROM [User] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE LEN([t1].[value]) > @p6
```

Seems Linq-to-SQL is **smarter** than Entity Framework, string process performed only once.

Answer (score 0):

Visualized version of [leppie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641963/4990642).
As can be seen, the compiler yields error in the query with `into` unlike the latter one as accessing to first variable.

[image]