# Sort by number of child records using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have the following two table:

```
-Groups-
Id
Name

-Members-
Id
GroupId (Group.Id is related to Member.GroupId)
Name
IsActive (bit)
```

How can I writing a LINQ query that will sort by the number of IsActive members highest to lowest in a group?

The query would look something like this

```
//pseudo code
    from grp in database.Groups
    orderby Count(grp.Members.where(m=>m.IsActive == true)) descending
    select grp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [let clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) for this. 
As a result you will get following:

```
from grp in database.Groups
let activeCount = grp.Members.Where(m=>m.IsActive == true).Count()
order by activeCount descending
select grp
```

Another way to achive desired ordering is to use `select ... into`. Queries will be pretty similar, but you should be aware of differences between this two approaches: [Is linq's let keyword better than its into keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641931/is-linqs-let-keyword-better-than-its-into-keyword)